# Gitorious. Проблема с push из под windows.

Tags: git

Решил потестить для себя GITORIOUS.
Настраивал дома (kubuntu) все хорошо, по инструкции.
На работе windows машина. При попытке push пишет

```
$ git push origin master
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
...
Connection abandoned.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Хотя перед этим соединение по ssh проходит нормально:

```
$ ssh git@gitorious.org
Welcome, decodder. Use git to push/pull your repositories
Connection to gitorious.org closed.
```

Слышал мнение, что Git не находит путь к .ssh. Как это можно проверить и в чем может быть еще проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Помогает отзеркаливание.

```
$ git push –mirror https://github.com/your_login/your_repo.git
```

Подробнее [здесь](http://codezona.com/git-and-github.html)